# How to compile PHP-CPP on Windows?

Tags: php, c++11, mingw, php-cpp

I'm compiling **PHP-CPP** source but i getting error in **Windows 7**.But, in **Linux** (for .so extension) it works fine. The error given by the compiler is:
**collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status**

**Note: I'm using PHP-CPP not PHP source code directly...**

> Error: mkdir -p shared/common The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>   Makefile:190: recipe for target 'shared_directories' failed
>   mingw32-make: *** [shared_directories] Error 1

[PHP-CPP (i'm using)](http://modsolutionz.com/PHP-CPP.zip)

[Error Image](http://modsolutionz.com/error.png)

Comment: That's just a generic error that means "something failed". The actual problem is in the 10-20 lines before that. Please post that.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are using MinGW (mingw32-make) in a cmd.exe hosted environment; cmd.exe's mkdir (md) command doesn't offer a -p option, AFAIK.  Your makefile appears to expect a POSIX shell hosted environment, so you may have better luck with such, (e.g. the bash shell furnished by MinGW.org's MSYS, or by Cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the newest release of phpcpp - then make a build with cmake (just use the cmake gui for windows) - here it's important to set the follwoing entries for build:

**PHPCPP_ARCH** with "**x86_64**" and
**PHPCPP_PHP_PATH** to the path where your root dir of the php source is ...

if you want to build for static libs - set this:

**PHPCPP_MSVCRT_STATIC**

if you want to have a dynamic build just don't set this Entry ...

Now just click on "**Configure**" - when its completed just hit "**Generate**" ..

if all works fine you can now click on "**Open Project**" and usualy now Visual Studio will load the data needed for compiling ...

Now just compile and now you can use **.lib** / **.dll** for further implementations ...